# angularjs set a class in the main template better way

Tags: angularjs

in my main template

```
<body data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id="container" data-ng-class="{home: home}">
```

in my controller

```
.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$location) {
       $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
        if($location.path()==='/'){
          $scope.home = true;  
        }
        else{
          $scope.home = false;  
        }
}
```

my goal is set a class only if the router is running
IndexCtrl

```
.config(function (CONFIG,$routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: CONFIG.site.path_views + '/index/index.html',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
   })
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

In MainCtrl:

```
$scope.$location = $location;
```

In HTML:

```
<div id="container" data-ng-class="{home: $location.path()==='/'}">
```

This would however cause continuous calls to $location.path(). Your approach does waste less processing power.